# android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, mImageUri) throws out of memory exception

Tags: android, camera

Iam getting out of memory error after clicking image from camera. My code to get  bitmap is :

```
public void grabImage(ImageView imageView) {
    this.getContentResolver().notifyChange(mImageUri, null);
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try {
        //getting crash on this line
        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr,      mImageUri);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50 / 100, byteArrayOutputStream);


        getImageUri(this, bitmap);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to load", e);
    }catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load images.

Comment: You can use Fresco too. Link https://github.com/facebook/fresco

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344081/android-how-to-use-bitmap-factory-to-compress-image-without-reduce-the-quality/50344790#50344790